# Database that doesn't require installation and works with fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Which databases do Fluent NHibernate support and don't require installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate (and therefore Fluent) supports SQLite and SQL CE